# Haskell -- How should I avoid head or tail, and adopt pattern matching?

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell, and I have been told that I should avoid using head and tail for list operation and use pattern matching instead. I got a code snippet here, and I wonder how should this be converted so that no head or tail is used?

```
myzipWith :: (a->b->c) -> [a] -> [b] ->[c]
myzipWith func [] [] = []
myzipWith func listA listB =
    [func (head listA) (head listB) ] ++ (myzipWith func (tail listA) (tail listB))
```

Comment: Replace the final equation with `myzipWith func (x:xs) (y:ys) = func x y : myzipWith func xs ys`.

Comment: There are good reasons to avoid `head` and `tail`. Let me ask, out of curiosity: were you given them?

Comment: Knowing how `head` and `tail` are defined should help: `head (x:_) = x` and `tail (_:xs) = xs`.

Comment: @chepner I know the definition but I was just not so familiar how to deal with the input parameter (sry idk whether I have used a right term) alongside with the function signature. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myzipWith :: (a->b->c) -> [a] -> [b] ->[c]
myzipWith func [] [] = []
myzipWith func (headA:restA) (headB:restB) =
    [func headA headB] ++ myzipWith func restA restB
```

But note the append (`++`) isn't necessary. This would be more idiomatic (and efficient):

```
    func headA headB : myzipWith func restA restB
```

Comment: Also note that the pattern matching is not exhaustive, as turning on warnings should point out.

Comment: To deal with all the (three) edge cases elegantly, it's probably best to remove the first line of your definition and add `myzipWith _ _ _ = []` after the other line - "given any lists that don't match, return `[]`".

Comment: While your suggestion is more idiomatic, it's not any more efficient, in fact i suspect it will generate exactly the same code, since `++` will be inlined.

Comment: @luqui, likely, with optimizations, but desugaring list literals to optimize well is all sorts of tricky. I wouldn't really want to rely on it when I don't have to.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments, it was helpful and I have understand more on this subject :) Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

```
myzipWith func (a:as) (b:bs) = [func a b] ++ (myzipWith func as bs)
```

The syntax `function (x:xs)` splits the list passed to `function` into two parts: the first element `x` and the rest of the list `xs`.